# Running a script on sequential IDs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run the same script per instance of ID

For example, if a user clicks the button with #btn-1, the script would run for #title-1 to grab the html and proceed with opening the popup and scrollTop.

I have a crude working example, but I would like to know how this could be made more concise without the need for such repetition.

PHP

```
<h2 id="title-<?php echo $i ;?>">Product Title</h2> 
<div id="btn-<?php echo $i ;?>">Sign Up</div>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#btn-1").click(function(){
        var name = $("#title-1").html();
        $("#product").val(name);
        $("#the_popup, #overlay_pop").fadeIn(500);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
        return false;
    });
    $("#btn-2").click(function(){
        var name = $("#title-2").html();
        $("#product").val(name);
        $("#the_popup, #overlay_pop").fadeIn(500);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
        return false;
    });
    $("#btn-3").click(function(){
        var name = $("#title-3").html();
        $("#product").val(name);
        $("#the_popup, #overlay_pop").fadeIn(500);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
        return false;
    });

    // and so on....
```

Comment: Could you provide your html? You can use custom data attributes, for example....

Comment: Start by putting the identical code in a new function with a parameter for `#title-1` etc.

Comment: It's dynamically generated using PHP, so each instance would have it's own ID.. like so...

<h2 id="title-<?php echo $i ;?>">Product Title</h2>
<div id="btn-<?php echo $i ;?>Sign Up</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('button[id^="btn-"]') All buttons with a id attribute value starting with "btn-" then attach the click handler.

Then use regex to strip the number from the id. Then use that number to find the corresponding #title*

```
$("button[id^=btn-]").click(function (e) {
    var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var name = $("#title-" + num).html();
    $("#product").val(name);
    $("#the_popup, #overlay_pop").fadeIn(500);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/uux332yt/

Can certainly be done easier by accessing classes.

Comment: Thanks Sean. This is exactly what I was looking to achieve!

Answer (score 2):

Use a class - without knowing the rest of your HTML you want something like

```
<h2 class="title">Product Title</h2> 
<div class="btn">Sign Up</div>



$(".btn").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).prev(".title").html();

    $(this).find(".product").val(name);

    $(this).find(".the_popup, .overlay_pop").fadeIn(500);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it. To the OP, using classes in this way instead of a ton of IDs will save you a lot of trouble in the future. Great answer.

Comment: My answer is based off OP however classes and relation to the item in the classes like @mplungjan's example would be the best way to handle the events.